# Is it "StackOverflow", or "Stack Overflow"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I just came across [this edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/14481/revisions), which would never have been approved if the user had < 2K rep, and I'm wondering if it's even legit.

So, what is the proper name to use when referring to the site?

Comment: Stack Overflow™ :P

Comment: If ever anybody cares it is MathOverflow, though.

Comment: Ahhh...  When you look at the logo, it looks like it's one word, yet I've seen other places where it's clearly 2.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, Intel's logo is lower case. The stylistic choices of a logo do not affect how they are officially incorporated or referred to in text.

Answer (score 12):

[The site's name is "Stack Overflow"](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), not "Stackoverflow" or "StackOverflow".

Also note that minor edits, while they are not acceptable suggested edits, are not prohibited as full edits, given that they are not consuming the time of 2-5 reviewers nor are they locking the post from other edits for a period of time.  Larger, more comprehensive edits are...preferable, so as to not bump posts to the top of the "active" list without warrant, but it's much less of a problem.

Answer (score 9):

To provide an official slant; this is from the [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) part of the legal page:

> Stack Overflow is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written **stackoverflow.com** (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is "Stack Overflow" , that is how it is being referred.

From Flagging a post:

> Programming questions are off-topic on Meta Stack Overflow. Please
>   refer to how to ask on **Stack Overflow**.